# 0 txn in mined block

Tags: mining, blocks, block-reward

How is it possible for a block to be mined with 0 txn?

https://etherscan.io/block/6739171

That's an easy way to get 3 ETH block rewards.

Comment: That's not an easy way. You still have to solve PoW puzzle and race with other miners.

Answer (score 1):

Mining empty blocks is valid, miners don't do it because they would get more profits if they include transactions since they get the gas.

Mining an empty block is not easier than mining a full one, the process is the exact same, they generate a block and try nonces until they get a valid one which gives them the right to publish the block.

Some people argue that if your block is too full, it will take longer to broadcast it to the network, increasing the risk of becoming an uncle block, but we are talking about differences of milliseconds, and most miners choose to fill their blocks because the reward is higher than the risk.

By looking at the block, it might have been mined by BTC.com, their intentions to do this are pure speculation, but include publicity, or hurting the network by slowing it down. (Probably the first one).

Answer (score 1):

it's possible, miners needs to get paid for their work... but they still have to solve the hash in order to do it. See Alcazar answer :) he's faster than me :)